# Pivot Table Expand "Values" VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, pivot-table

I am trying to automatically adding fields to an already created Pivot table. The fields would "sum of period 1" ... "sum of period 360". I already have periods 1-60, but am missing 61-360. It will be a pain to manually drag down 300 times. So I wrote a macro, but I get the error:
 **unable to get pivot items property of the pivot field class**

Since the pivot table is already created (it's a big table with many format quirks), I don't want to change anything. I just want to add the periods as sum of values from period61-period360.

I've attached my code. Any help anyone could give me will be very much appreciate as I don't know what I am doing wrong and I'm trying to not get too frustrated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Here is my code:

```
'--------------------- Expand_Pivot_to_360M Macro-------------------'

Sub Expand_Pivot_to_360M()

' Setting Pivot field classes to the "unable to get pivot items property of the pivot field class" error
    Sheets("Monthly Summary").Select

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("universe")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("buckets_break")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("pool_name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 3
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("gl_company_code")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 4
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("LEP")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 5
    End With
```

Loop to Expand Pivit 360 periods

```
' Using a Loop to Expand Pivot for 360 periods
    Dim i As Integer

        For i = 61 To 360       ' start at period 61 since periods 1 to 60 already include in pivot

            Sheets("Monthly Summary").Select
            ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
                "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Period_i"), "Sum of Period_i", xlSum
            With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of Period_i")
                .Caption = "Count of Period_i"
                .Function = xlCount
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Count of Period_i")
                .Caption = "Sum of Period_i"
                .Function = xlSum
            End With

        Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: replace `_i"` with `_" & i`

Comment: thank you, I did that and no longer get the "unable to get pivot items property..." error but i do get another error: application-defined or object-defined error". Please let me know if you can help, any ideas  to fix this? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of extraneous code generated from the macro recording. Also, you are possibly getting the "application-defined or object-defined error" message because one or more of the fields you are trying to add already exist.

I would suggest this ...

```
Dim i as Integer
Dim found as Boolean
Dim aPItem as PivotItem
With Sheets("Monthly Summary").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    For i = 61 to 360
        found = false
        For Each aPItem In .DataPivotField.PivotItems 'Check field not already there
            If aPItem.Caption = "Sum of Period_" & i Then
                found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next aPItem

        If Not found then 'add field
            .AddDataField .PivotFields("Period_" & i), "Sum of Period_" & i, xlSum
        End If
    Next i
End With
```